# datagridview date sorting c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am using an SQLite database with a date field.  I am storing the date as text.  When I put the data into a datatable and set the datagridview datasource to the datatable the dates sort as strings (1/1/2018 will come before 1/2/2015 for example).  Short of storing my date as yyyy/MM/dd I can't get the dates to sort correctly.  This is the code I used to get the data into the datagridview.  dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"; did nothing.

```
con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Date, PartNo FROM tblTest";
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
            //this for loop was an attempt to ensure the datagridview received dates and not strings
            //didn't solve my problem
            for (int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                DateTime dtDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                dt.Rows[i][0] = dtDate;
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Change your table structure now / early on while you can... Store dates as date fields not text.  Once you pull data down, then you can format however else, but the inverse is a PITA.  Also try to NOT use reserved keywords as column names, can be confusing and problematic later on.

Comment: The string `'1/1/2018'` is lexicographically less than the string `'1/2/2015'`, yes. If you want to store dates as strings in sqlite (instead of as a numeric format) and be able to sort or compare them, use `'YYYY-MM-DD'` which has the extra benefit of being understood by it's time and date functions.

Comment: @DRapp sqlite doesn't have a date type. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thanks guys.  I settled on storing my date as a julian number and then converting it in the SQL statement. This is where I found it in case it helps anyone else. http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/

Comment: Great.. Julian number. I hope you are at least doing Julian 5-digit for YYddd, otherwise, what happens on Julian day 1 next year

Comment: //textbox5.text is a date entered by the user

DateTime dtDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox5.Text);
double jDate = dtDate.ToOADate() + 2415018.5;

I save jDate to the database.  When I retrieve the date,
I use this statement:

"SELECT date(jDate) FROM tblReceiving" 
I get the date in yyyy/mm/dd format.